# Differential equation with absolute value?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know how to solve this differential equation
$ y''+|y+1|=-e^x$ with these initial conditions $y(0)=-1$ and $ y'(0)=0 $

In particular I don't know how to deal with the absolute value. The only thing that I know is that the second derivative is always negative and therefore $y'$ is monotonically decreasing but how can I determine the sign of the function?
Thanks a lot in advice

Comment: In this particular case I think $y+1$ stays nonpositive forever. (That depends on the initial condition of course.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't understand how the sign is related to the initial conditions. I know that $y+1$ passes for $(0,0)$ and its derivative too but then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $y'' < 0\, \forall x$, $y'$ is monotonically decreasing. Since $y'(0) = 0$, we have:

If $x < 0$, $y' > 0$ and $y$ is monotonically increasing,

If $x > 0$, $y' > 0$ and $y$ is monotonically decreasing.

Therefore $x = 0$ is an absolute maximum, and $y < -1, \forall x$. The equation simplifies to

$$ y'' - (y+1) = -e^x $$